# Restart ServerSocket after IOException

Tags: java, serversocket, ioexception

How to restart `ServerSocket` after `IOException`?

My server socket sometimes gets an `EOFException` and then stops accepting new connections. To solve this I have tried closing the old server socket and creating a new one after the exception is thrown. However even after the new server socket is created, new connections are not accepted. Can some one see why this does not work?

```
public Server() throws IOException {        
  try {
    listen(port);
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Server() - IO exception");
    System.out.println(e);

    /*when an exception is caught I close the server socket and try opening it a new one */
    serverSocket.close();

    listen(port);
  }
}

private void listen(int port) throws IOException {
  serverIsListening = true;

  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
  System.out.println("<Listening> Port: " + serverSocket);

  while (serverIsListening) {
    if (eofExceptionThrown){  //manually triggering an exception to troubleshoot
      serverIsListening = false;
      throw new EOFException();
    }

    //accept the next incoming connection
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("[New Conn] " + socket);

    ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    // Save the streams
    socketToOutputStreams.put(socket, oOut);

    // Create a new thread for this connection, and put it in the hash table
    socketToServerThread.put(socket, new ServerThread(this, socket));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide new connection do not accepter? Is some exception thrown? Or you cannot create the new socket? Or is it just ignore new client?

Comment: When I connect a new client after the exception is thrown and the server ignores it, i.e. it does not print the `[New Conn]` message.

Comment: i might be wrong, because i'm not sure about that. but you can check that you triggered EOF exception manually. but in your Server() code, you're catching IOException. make sure, if it has tha same effect.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that `EOFException` inherits `IOException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2x entry point , one form catch: never ends well.

```
  try {
    listen(port);
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Server() - IO exception");
    System.out.println(e);

    /*when an exception is caught I close the server socket and try opening it a new one */
    serverSocket.close();

    listen(port);
  }
```

I would do in a loop, while a boolean is true:

```
while(needToListen){
  try{
     listen(port)
   }catch(Exception ex){
     if(exception   is what needed to break the loop, like a message has a string on it){
       break;
     }
   }
}

  if(needToListen){
      Log.e("something unexpected, unrecoverable....");
  }
```

Comment: I added a nested `try catch` to cover the second call to `listen()`. It seems the problem is that the `EOFException` is being thrown the second time. The solution was to set `eofExceptionThrown` to false before calling `listen()` again. Your answer lead me to this so I am marking you as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> My server socket sometimes gets an EOFException and then stops accepting new connections

No it doesn't. `ServerSockets` never get `EOFExceptions`. Rather, one of your accepted `Sockets` is getting an `EOFException`, which is only to be expected, and you are closing both that `Socket`, which is correct, *and* the `ServerSocket`, which is incorrect. Exceptions on accepted sockets don't affect the listening socket.